# I am trying to send a request from nextjs to springboot and cors stops it

Tags: spring-boot, next.js

Problem
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/user/username/endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf( c -> c.disable());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests( c ->{
                    c.requestMatchers("/user/login","/user/register").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                });
        http.formLogin( c->{
           c.disable();
        });
        http.logout(c -> c.permitAll());
        http.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
        http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*"); // Allow requests from any origin
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*"); // Allow all HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*"); // Allow all headers
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true); // Allow sending cookies
        configuration.setMaxAge(360000l);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}


    fetch("http://localhost:8080/user/"+localStorage.getItem("user")+"/endpoint",{
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: You have to fix this on your webserver. I had the same problem with IIS and only changing the Web.config file solved it.